# Implemented the Huawei Full ads SDK Ads on the GMS devices but Ads not coming Why?

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, appgallery, appgallery-connect, huawei-ads

I had implemented the **Huawei Full Ads SDK Ads** on the *GMS devices* and after that the ads were not coming up Why?

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If your app is only released on Google Play but is not released on AppGallery, you need to complete the following configuration and submit a monetization application for your app. Your app can start traffic monetization only after the application is approved: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/monetize/addmedia-gp-0000001149967192